# Reading a property file and saving to an object

Tags: java

I have property file called `person.properties`. I need to add several person entries in.
A person entry will have a `Name`, `Age`, `Telephone`. There will be many Person entries in this Property file.

```
ID : 1
Name: joe
Age: 30
Telephone: 444444
ID : 2
Name: Anne
Age: 20
Telephone: 575757
ID : 3
Name: Matt
Age: 17
Telephone : 7878787
ID : 4
Name: Chris
Age: 21
Telephone : 6767676
```

I need to read the property file and save each record in an `Person` object.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setId(ADD THE FIRST VALUE OF ID FROM THE PROPERTY FILE);
p.setName(ADD THE FIRST VALUE OF NAME FROM THE PROPERTY FILE);
```

like wise.. and save it in an array.

I think, that i will not be able to read from the person.properties file above and save it to the person object as i require. Because i am having the same `key` in the property file. Therefore how can i achieve this?

Comment: perhaps you should be using some sort of serialization library...not property files.

Comment: When i try to read the `name` key from the property file it will not know which `name ` `key` to refer, because there are loads of `name` `key`'s in that property file .

Comment: you can read strings from file and then parse each string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file format you describe is not really a properties file. Just read it yourself, using something like

```
public File openFile(String URI); // write this yourself

public void readFile(File names) {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));

  while(br.ready()) {
    String next = br.readLine();
    String[] split = next.split(" : ");
    // handle each case, etc.
```

---

### Modification of file

If you want to modify the key and write it back to the same position, you should use a database. Here are two free ones: [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It's possible to edit the file in that way, but it's much easier to just do it with a database, that's what it's designed for.

Comment: And, what if i want to modify the key and write it back to the same position. Will your approach work ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use the `Property` methods for this, you can simply read the file as a text file and parse it manually:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("propertyfile.properties"));
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String id = s.nextLine().split(":")[1].trim();
    String name = s.nextLine().split(":")[1].trim();
    String age = s.nextLine().split(":")[1].trim();
    String phone = s.nextLine().split(":")[1].trim();
}
```

Comment: And, what if i want to modify the key and write it back to the same position. Will your approach work ?

Comment: Possible, yes, though maybe you would want to dump the complete list of persons to the file at once.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is actually not the purpose of property files in java, I think. Nevertheless, here is how to handle property files:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
           //load a properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("file.properties"));

           //get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("name"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("age"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("telephone"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Could this help you or what you actually want to do?

I think for your approach a database style thingy would be better.

Comment: yeah, some string reading like the others say, would do it as well :P